# C++ simple object destruction error

Tags: c++

I have written a code which contains a const variable in its class declaration. However I initialize the value of the variable in a function of the class. And I can use that variable without any pain throughout that class. But when I try to access that variable via another function of the class I cannot . It seems its value is set to `NULL`. Here is the declaration of the class (the variable part only)

```
public:
    const aiScene *pScene;
```

And I am initializing it in a function named `LoadModel()`

```
pScene = imp.ReadFile(fileName,
    aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace |
    aiProcess_ConvertToLeftHanded |
    aiProcess_Triangulate |
    aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals |
    aiProcess_OptimizeMeshes);

if (pScene == NULL)
    MessageBoxA(NULL, imp.GetErrorString(), "Error", MB_OK);
```

If I call a function called `Update()` in this `LoadModel()` function which uses this variable it works perfectly but when I call it in `Render()` function of the same class the program crashes. I can see in the debugger that the `pScene` has some error "Unable to read memory"

Comment: The `pScene` member isn't const anyway; what it points to is const.

Comment: `I initialize the value of the variable in a function of the class` Not possible. You are confusing _initialisation_ and _assignment_.

Comment: Ok but why it is empty when I try to access it via other function ? Isn't it a class variable which can be accessed by any member function ?

Comment: @user3163223: Yes, it should be. It has been modified by some of your code somewhere, or overwritten by memory corruption. Without a [minimal testcase](http://sscce.org) any further guessing on my part would be pointless. Note that unless you can prove otherwise, there is no reason to assume the pointer has become `NULL` specifically.

Comment: An inaccessible location looks like an overwrite of the pointer, either in Render() or by code preceding the call to Render(). You can do some printf debugging by printing the value of pScene directly after ReadFile() and at strategic points after that.

Comment: Guess I have to reassign the pointer when I access the function

Comment: Again, does assignment have to do anything with that ? I am currently finding references to the variable throughout the code

Comment: Another issue is (sorry of it sounds silly): ReadFile() _does_ return dynamic memory, right? I.e. not something on its own stack. Because I don't see you passing the pointer in which would be a standard pattern.

Comment: I hope that it returns dynamic memory. And if it does not than I guess there is a good chance that it gets destroyed with "imp".

Comment: Oh, it's not from you? Then you should have documentation with it.

Comment: Ok making the imp variable seemed to have solved the problem. It was getting destroyed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the variable "imp" global. Silly mistake....

Comment: I think the disccussion helped finding the error so it was not in vain.